# Conditional Formatting using multiple conditions - Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I have trouble putting conditions for a range of cells with names in an Excel 2007 workbook. I need to highlight the cells in that range which contain names that begin or end in a vowel. Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enter the relevant vowels in a range of cells (one each) and name that range `Vowel` then select entire worksheet and with “Use a formula to determine which cells to format” set:

```
=OR(COUNTIF(Vowel,RIGHT(A1,1)),COUNTIF(Vowel,LEFT(A1,1)))
```

in “Format values where this formula is true:” with formatting of choice and Applies to range reduced to suit.